# Typescript generic and NonNullable

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a typing issue with my generic function. The issue appears though several third-party libraries, but I managed to build minimal example.

```js
interface MyType {
  id: string;
}

function myFunction<T extends MyType>(param: T) {
  // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'NonNullable<T["id"]>'.
  const a: NonNullable<T["id"]> = "my-id";
  console.log(a);
}
```

If I rewrite this function without generic, typing works fine:

```js
function myFunction(param: MyType) {
  const a: NonNullable<MyType["id"]> = "my-id";
  console.log(a);
}
```

I checked generics documentation and can't find why the first code is incorrect. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to and including TypeScript 4.7, [the `NonNullable<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) was [implemented as](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/481357a4c83206591091b9b88016e208e3959fce/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1521) a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), `T extends null | undefined ? never : T`.

When a conditional type depends on a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter, as in the type `NonNullable<T["id"]>` inside the body of `myFunction()`, the compiler completely *defers* evaluation of it; it just doesn't know what type it is yet, at all.  Such types are essentially *opaque* to the compiler, so it cannot verify that a value of any other type is assignable to it.  You need to refactor or use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to perform such an assignment:

```
const a = "my-id" as NonNullable<T["id"]>; // okay, TS4.7-
```

---

Luckily, [TypeScript 4.8 will introduce some better intersection reduction and narrowing support](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8-beta/#improved-intersection-reduction-union-compatibility-and-narrowing) that includes [re-defining](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9a09c37878a45b06994485fdb510eb4d24587dcb/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1587) `NonNullable<T>` as `T & {}`.  That is, instead of a conditional type, it's just an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with the [empty object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-oop.html#empty-types) (which can be anything except `null` or `undefined`).  Details about how this works are in [microsoft/TypeScript#49119](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/49119), but for your purposes all you need to know is that your original example will just start working:

```
const a: NonNullable<T["id"]> = "my-id"; // okay TS4.8+
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAsAFDLLAAmAXMgM5hSgDmA3CQL4kkwCuICYYAHsQyALboAYnwHCQAHkzIIAD0ggKtNFlwQAfAAoccKHDE1MASmRFSyBCPrI4NAHIjXPADZe4AIy8IRQBtACJKUIBdPWQAXmRQiQBaCJZkAHp05CEAazh0ZEwAZQAWADoADgBqEjIHEFohQLKvISYDOEs2YnYgA)